# What principle does the attitude indicator in the G1000 use?

Tags: avionics, heading, attitude

The heading indicator in the G1000 uses a magnetometor, but how can the attitude indicator work in the G1000?

Does it work with a tilt sensor, rate sensor or accelerometer?

Answer (score 5):

G1000 is a multi-unit system. The attitude information comes from a specialised unit called AHRS (Attitude and Heading Reference System), typically GRS 77. AHRS uses two solid-state gyros (vertical and directional), plus a magnetometer, to obtain a complete attitude information.

In addition, AHRS does employ accelerometers and rate gyros. Their data is used for stabilisation, filtering, and as an input for autopilot and other systems.

Comment: "AHRS uses two solid-state gyros (vertical and directional)" - Does this mean that the AHRS uses gyros to sense the pitch rate and roll rate, but not the yaw rate?

Comment: A gyro, whether attitude (angle) or rate one, can (technically) measure two out of three angles. So in fact they have an overlap.